# Issue with hostname on Windows Server 2012 domain controller

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, hostname

We moved sites recently and since the move I have been unable to get the DC to respond to pings / file locations using the hostname - it can be pinged fine, and I can ping the hostname from the DC itself but not from any other PC on the domain.

I'm a little stuck as nothing has changed, I've updated DNS entries on the DC to the new IP

Comment: Apologies I should of said, this is windows server 2012

Comment: Are the clients using this same DC for DNS services? Sounds like they are not.  If the clients Use DHCP are they receiving the correct information/options? If the clients are hard coded do they have the proper DNS servers configured?